# How do I make two ExtJS pies have the same colors for the same slice names if I can't guarantee they'll both have all the same categories?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to make a pair of ExtJS charts that have the same colors for the slices that have the same names.  For example, if I have a chart that has state populations and another that has state life expectancies, I want Maryland in both to have the same color.

I can do that pretty easily using colorSet; however, colorSet applies colors in order so if one of the pies skips a state, then the colors no longer match

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that with the fix to ExtJS, it's ok if some of the data is null.  Therefore, if I sort the data and provide a sorted array of colors, they'll be applied in order.  And if there is no Maryland in one, it will still skip to the next color for whatever comes next.